# Make multiple links in a row the same dynamic height

Tags: html, css, height

I have a web page with multiple links that contain a medium-sized image and a short descriptive text underneath. While all images have the same size (for now), the text comes from a translation and may span a variable number of lines, depending on the text length.

Much like in a toolbar, all links must have the same height. Especially the background hover highlighting must show the same height of all items, and of course the link-sensitive area must match the background highlighting, thus the actual `<a>` element needs to have that height.

I know I could use JavaScript to determine the maximum height of the link items and apply it as fixed height to all of them. But I'd try to avoid using JavaScript for that and rely on CSS only.

My original attempt was to use tables for that and make the links expand to the entire row cell height, but that doesn't work (has no effect).

So here's something else without tables that also doesn't work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    background: #eeeeee;
    border: dotted 1px red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<a>
Line 1<br>
Line 2<br>
Line 3<br>
</a>

<a>
Line 1<br>
</a>

<a>
Line 1<br>
Line 2<br>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is wrap them in a container with [`table` display](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#value-def-table) and give each of your anchor elements a `table-cell` display:

```
<div class="table">
    <a>
        Line 1<br>
        Line 2<br>
        Line 3<br>
    </a>

    <a>
        Line 1<br>
    </a>
</div>
```

Styled using:

```
div.table {
    display:table;
}

div.table a {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rAwTz/).

Comment: Probably the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>
                Line 1<br>
                Line 2<br>
                Line 3<br>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>
                Line 1<br>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>
                Line 1<br>
                Line 2<br>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csTpY/3/)

Comment: @Marc Audet display block does not work. And yes, you can add the width:100px to the a element if you want all the <a> to have the same width. Finally, just out of curiosity, what's missing with this solution?

Comment: In your example, each `a` will have a different height (3,1,2 lines respectively).  When you hover over them and add a background color, you will get a block of different height.  The OP wants the `a` elements to all have the same height.

Comment: @Marc Audet see my updated Fiddle, i added the :hover

Comment: I mispoke in my earlier comment.  Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ETDhP/ If you set the `height: 100%` to the `table` and `td` elements, then setting `height: 100%` on `a` will scale the links to all have the same heights.

Comment: @Marc Audet i found out that my solution only works on Chrome, sorry for that.

Comment: That looks strange. It does work in Firefox, but from `table { height: 100%; }` I would have expected the entire table to fill the page height or something. At least that's what it used to do ten years ago, IIRC. The `display: table-cell;` solution in the other answer looks more convincing...